# Issue in iPhoneX while play sound volume is Mute

Tags: ios, swift

playing a system sound code like

```
var aSound:SystemSoundID = 1057
if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ios_7_bamboo", withExtension: "mp3") {
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &aSound)
    print("Initialised aSound:\(aSound)")
} else {
    print("You have forgotten to add your sound file to the app.")
}
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(aSound)
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1520)
```

using this code when click  on button i play sound 
it is working in iPhone 7,6 while mute, you cant hear sound 
but in iPhone x if i mute sound i can Hear a sound 
how i can set sound no Hearing while if volume is mute also i want to set in volume is reduce so button click sound also reduce

Thanks you